# When JodaTime v. 2.5 library included into WAR file deployment fails

Tags: cdi, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

When JodaTime v. 2.5 library included into WAR file deployment fails in GF 5.0 with following error. It seems problem lies in hibernate-validator. FutureValidatorForReadableInstant is not loaded as ReadableInstant is not loaded by hibernate-validator bundle in GF5.0 while it is working GF 4.1.2.

Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:Errornstantiating :org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension

```
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.joda.time.ReadableInstant not present
at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
at sun.reflect.generics.repository.ClassRepository.getSuperclass(ClassRepository.java:90)
at java.lang.Class.getGenericSuperclass(Class.java:777)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper.resolveTypeForClassAndHierarchy(TypeHelper.java:386)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper.resolveTypes(TypeHelper.java:351)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.TypeHelper.extractType(TypeHelper.java:327)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.(ClassBasedValidatorDescriptor.java:39)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintValidatorDescriptor.forClass(ConstraintValidatorDescriptor.java:49)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.putConstraints(ConstraintHelper.java:686)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.ConstraintHelper.(ConstraintHelper.java:386)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:155)
at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:322)
at org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.ValidationExtension.(ValidationExtension.java:116)
... 78 more
```

Comment: In hibernate-validator 6.0.2.Final if joda jar is available in web app it adds "FutureValidatorForReadableInstant" in to validator list refer https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/6.0.2.Final/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/metadata/core/ConstraintHelper.java#L367

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it might be a bug in Hibernate Validator. I created https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1490 to track this issue.

When we try to detect Joda Time in ConstraintHelper, we use the LoadClass mechanism which might fall back to using the Thread Context class loader if it does not find the class within the ConstraintHelper/HV CL.

In your case, I think the ReadableInstant class is accessible in the TCCL but not in the HV CL.

When we try to get the type from the ConstraintValidator, we only have the HV CL and so it fails to find the class.

So I think we should fix that in HV but I'm not sure it will help you as, once fixed, the Joda Time constraint validators won't be enabled anyway.

What might not help is that the OSGi bundle of HV looks a bit outdated regarding the Joda Time dependency (https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/master/nucleus/packager/external/bean-validator/pom.xml#L124). I'll see with the GlassFish team if they can update it.

I created a PR https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/pull/857 to fix the issue on our side. You might be able to get this branch, build it (it's just a mvn clean install) and upgrade the jars in your GlassFish. As mentioned above, it won't allow you to use constraints on Joda Time types but, at least, you should be able to start your app. I'm interested in your feedback if you can try that.

About the GF part, I emailed the GF team and will let you know if there is some progress on that front.

Update: GF 5.0.1 will contain a fix for this issue. If you upgrade your current GF to HV 6.0.3.Final we released today, you should be able to start your app (but won't be able to put constraints on Joda Time types, this would have to wait for GF 5.0.1).

Comment: Hello Guillaume, I could really use your help. I am not sure of how to update library versions in GF5. Could you tell me how, or at least point me in the right direction (maybe documentation?). Thanks in advance.